# Clicking on a tag on SO for teams allows you to click "Top Users" but nothing is ever there

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

We use SO for Teams and have tags where I ask or answer a lot of questions.  However, when we click on a tag and click "Top Users" on every tag we create we don't have any top users?  Seems to be a bug to me as I have one tag where I have asked or answered 10 out of 11 questions related to this tag.  Should I not be a top user of this tag ?

This includes all time and last X days...

Comment: @stackoverflow teams team - any update or at least confirmation that this is in fact a bug?

Comment: Is this still an issue?  We see that the table backing that "Tags Top Users" view has data (but not what that data is).  We'd need permission to access your Team's database to troubleshoot further.

Answer (score 2):

This should now be fixed! Please let us know if it's still not working for you.